# How to output an array in Javascript like a social media feed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, feed

I'm using React for my application and I've put my data (objects) into an array. Is there a way to output my data (array of objects) that loads all at once (such as Twitter, Instagram, Facebook)?

Currently I'm using a for loop where it loads one by one from my latest post to the end.

Here's a sample for loop to demonstrate.

```
var myArray = [
    {name: 'Dwayne', age: 28},
    {name: 'Rob', age: 32},
    {name: 'Marie', age: 22},
    {name: 'Sarah', age: 40},
    {name: 'Emma', age: 29},
    {name: 'James', age: 30}
];

for (var i = myArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log(myArray[i].name, myArray[i].age);
}
```

Comment: Typically you would use `.map()`... If you show the rest of your code, particularly your render function, you should get some good responses

Comment: Thanks Ted! Will try to change my code for it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of using map to generate a `<p/>` element with name and age inside it.

```
render(){
  const myArray = [
    {name: 'Dwayne', age: 28},
    {name: 'Rob', age: 32},
    {name: 'Marie', age: 22},
    {name: 'Sarah', age: 40},
    {name: 'Emma', age: 29},
    {name: 'James', age: 30}
  ];
  return(
    <div>
      {myArray.map((item, index) => (
        <p key={`${item.name}-${index}`}>
          Name:{item.name}, Age:{item.age}
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The above code would output

```
<div>
  <p>Name:Dwayne, Age:28</p>
  <p>Name:Rob, Age:32</p>
  <p>Name:Marie, Age:22</p>
  <p>Name:Sarah, Age:40</p>
  <p>Name:Emma, Age:29</p>
  <p>Name:James, Age:30</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I find this more understandable. Just wanted to clarify, what's `key={'${item.name}-${index}'` or what does it mean?
Still quite new to React.

Comment: @Aeriel Ah-- yes I should have explained that. When mapping arrays to elements like that, react uses the `key` prop to track the element internally to know if it has been updated and needs to be re-rendered. Keys need to be unique, so I used the name and index to guarantee that. You can remove the key to see the error that React will throw in the console. [Here's the documentation on keys for a full explanation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)